# Twilio Update a Task's current Queue

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-taskrouter

I'm using the TaskRouter to create a Workspace, Tasks, Queues, Workers and Workflows.

When a Task enters a queue I need to perform some operations that may take up to a minute before I want the task to go to the next queue even if there's 0 available resources in it's current queue.

Is there a way to manually update the Task\Call to put it in another queue? Or is there a Workflow configuration to prevent the Task from moving to the next queue for a certain amount of time or specific conditions have been met?

Answer (score 2):

TaskRouter engineer here!

Have a look at Workflow Timeouts [in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/workflow-configuration). They allow the Task to sit in a target for a period of time before falling down to the next target (which may or may not move its Queue as well, depending on how you configure the next Target.

You also mentioned *not* waiting before moving on to the next Queue. For this you'd use [a `skip_if` expression](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/worker-presence), which if evaluated to true immediately skips to the next target, regardless of the `timeout`.